# Adding Series during componentWillReceiveProps does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts, react-component

I have been at this for a while now and I'm stumped. I have a react component that is supposed to add a new series whenever it receives props, however `chart.getChart().addSeries({ data: [1, 2, 3, 4] })` is not showing the new series in my chart.  However, I also added a button to the component that `onClick` adds a new series, and that does work... Below is my code:

```
const config = {
  title: {
    text: 'Hello, World!'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
}
@autobind class SampleChart extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps({ data }) {
    if(data.length > 0) {
      this.chart.getChart().addSeries({data: [39.9, 81.5, 116.4, 229.2, 124.0, 174.0, 235.6, 138.5, 116.4, 94.1, 195.6, 54.4]}, false)
      this.chart.getChart().redraw()
    }
  }

  addSeries() {
    this.chart.getChart().addSeries({data: [39.9, 81.5, 116.4, 229.2, 124.0, 174.0, 235.6, 138.5, 116.4, 94.1, 195.6, 54.4]}, false)
    this.chart.getChart().redraw()
  }

render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <ReactHighcharts ref={(ref) => this.chart = ref} config={config} />
        <button onClick={this.addSeries}>add series</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default SampleChart
```

BTW, I do pass the `if(data.length > 0)` statement, and I'm experiencing this issue whenever I do pass a new set of props to my component. So this is not a component mounting issue (at least i don't think it is).
Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was happening. For posterity here is how you fix it:

Essentially what was wrong was `componentsWillReceiveProps()` triggers a render, and I think `this.chart.getChart().redraw()` didn't have time to redraw past the render. So I added:

```
componentShouldUpdate() {
  return false
}
```

That makes it work! Since the component doesn't render and the chart just redraws. However, what made this whole ordeal super confusing was that if you `setData()` the chart will redraw and update even without `componentShouldUpdate()`.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ujqpnw) you can see an example of how both of these cases react (`setData()` and `addSeries()`) when a `componehtShouldUpdate()` exists and when it doesn't.